# Actionscript 3 IDE

Tags: actionscript-3, ide

I'm currently using textmate with the actionscript 3 plugin to get as3 compile support. I'd like to use flash develop though, as it comes with much more, including code suggestions.

Is there any free and/or opensource alternative to flex builder/flash builder 4 that runs on a intel Mac?

Comment: Interesting, I was about to ask if anyone had tried Aptana Studio 2 or 3 with the Air plugin! I'm just about to download the beta version, but any comments would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use Eclipse IDE with the Flex SDK.

you can also get a free copy of Flash Builder 4 Standard from Adobe if you are a student, teacher or broke-ass developer:  http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/free/?sdid=GXVTO&PID=1225267

there's also Aptana which supports AIR and Flex:  http://www.aptana.com/

Comment: i've included the link for adobe's free Flash Builder 4 standard form

Comment: I have to say - I never knew Adobe was that charitable for (as you said) broke ass developers.  That's pretty sweet.

Comment: I'm a student at a school but unfortunately, i'm not sure how i'd be able to get it

Comment: it's a free download.  they don't send you a boxed copy.

Comment: I know, but also, you have to fill out a lot. I'm not sure if i can fill it out

Comment: As an update, they no longer offer Flash Builder for free :(

Answer (score 0):

I just run FlashDevelop in Parallels, works great. There's a lengthy discussion on the [FD forum](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewforum.php?f=9&sid=ab2f8067a3b20a3e0ab59725d0091c97) on how to configure it.

Comment: I don't have a spare windows licence.